# How does File::Find module work?

Tags: perl

I don't want to parse some of my subdirectories. For that, what are the things I can modify in these function below.

```
 use File::Find;
 find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);
 sub wanted { ... }
```

Here is my directory tree:

```
LOG
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
└── sdlog
    ├── 1log
    │   ├── a.txt
    │   └── b.txt
    └── 2log
        ├── a.txt
        └── b.txt
    |__abcd
    |__efgh
```

I want to parse **sdlogs** and **1log**. Apart from these subdirectories, I don't want to parse any other.

Comment: So it seems that you want to find only in `LOG/sdlog/1log`.

Comment: @  devnull .. Yes u are correct

Comment: How about reading the [manual](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/lib/File/Find.pm)?

Comment: Sir i have done it but could not get it .. that is the reason i have asked question here

Comment: I don't understand. Do you only care about one directory(1log)? Or can there possibly be more directories you want to search through below it?

Comment: No only one directory(1log) i am concern about.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `File::Find` here.

Have a look at [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# you probably want to use the abs. path
my $dir = "testdir";
opendir(my $dh, $dir);
# grep out directory files from the list of files to work on
# this will also skip "." and "..", obviously :)
my @files = grep { ! -d } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

# change to the given directory, as readdir doesn't return the relative path
# to @files. If you don't want to chdir, you can prepend the $dir to $file as 
# you operate on the $file
chdir $dir;
for my $file (@files) {
    # do stuff.. 
    # E.g., "open my $fh, ">>", $file;", etc

    print $file, "\n";
}
```

OUTPUT

```
$ ./test.pl
a_file.txt
b_file.txt
c_file.txt
```